# Mac volume reverts to Mac OS Extended

Tags: mac, disk-volume, hfs

All of our lab computers have file system type Mac OS Extended (Journaled) on the boot partition.  We needed to create a separate partition for use with a specific software, so we carved off 10 GB from the boot partition and made a 2nd partition (Examplify_backup).  We created the partition by booting from a USB drive and resizing the boot partition (it still had tons of space so 10 GB wasn't a big deal).  When we first did this we found that the file system had been set to Mac OS Extended [no Journaled] and since this format was read-only we had to reformat it.

That worked for a while, then the volumes on all the computers started reverting back to Mac OS Extended when they rebooted.  As of right now I can login to a computer as Admin, erase the partition and set the file system to Mac OS Extended (Journaled), it mounts the drive and I can write files to the drive.  However as soon as it reboots, it goes back to Mac OS Extended and the drive is read-only.

Any ideas?  It's kind of hard to search for help with Mac OS Extended right now without being bombarded with APFS posts.

**diskutil list** shows:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):    
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER    
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0    
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1    
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            990.0 GB   disk0s2    
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3    
   4:                  Apple_HFS Examplify_backup        9.2 GB     disk0s4
```

**diskutil info disk0s4** shows (among other things) either:

```
Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended
```

or

```
Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
Journal:                  Journal size 8192 KB at offset 0x47000
```

Comment: Can you run `diskutil list` and add the output to your post?

Comment: diskutil list posts the following:

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            990.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Examplify_backup        9.2 GB     disk0s4

Comment: Results of diskutil list are the same regardless of whether it's Mac OS Extended or Mac OS Extended (Journaled), but if i do diskutil info disk0s4 and it's not Journaled I get (among other things):

Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended

When it IS Journaled, it shows:

  Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
   Journal:                  Journal size 8192 KB at offset 0x47000